# HTML table parser to text with Java

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Help me please to parse this HTML table

[image: html table]

to text table like this one:

[image: text table]

I should do it with java and i chose jsoup. Know i have everything that I need, but I couldn't to paste symbols "-" in proper way. Somebody have any idea how to measure a width of table or I don't know, maybe another way. I clash with jsoup first time and I need a help.

**My code:**

```
public class SimpleParser {

    public void parseTable() throws IOException {
        File file = new File("C:\\Idea\\IdeaProjects\\SimpleParser\\src\\main\\resources\\table.html");
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(file, "UTF-8");
        Elements table = doc.select("table");
        reflection(table, new String(""));

    }
    public void reflection(Elements table, String star) {
        star += "*";

        for (int i = 0; i < table.size(); i++) {

            Elements trs = table.get(i).select("tr");

            for (int j = 0; j < trs.size(); j++) {
                if (tableChecker(trs.get(j).select("td"))) {
                } else System.out.println(String.format(("%s%s%s"), star, !!!Should be something!!!, star));
                Elements tds = trs.get(j).select("td");
                boolean st = false;

                for (int k = 0; k < tds.size(); k++) {
                    if (tds.get(k).select("table").size() != 0) {
                        j += tds.get(k).select("table").select("tr").size();
                        reflection(tds.get(k).select("table"), star);
                        k += tds.get(k).select("table").select("td").size();
                        if (k < tds.size() - 1) st = true;
                        i++;
                    }
                    else {
                        if (k == 0 || st) System.out.print(star);
                        st = false;
                        System.out.print(String.format(" %s ", tds.get(k).text()));
                        if (k == tds.size() - 1) System.out.print(star);
                        else System.out.print("|");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println(String.format(("%s%s%s"), star, "-----------------------------", star));
        }
    }

    public boolean tableChecker(Elements tds) {
        for (int k = 0; k < tds.size(); k++) {
            if (tds.get(k).select("table").size() != 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**My HTML:**

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Таблица размеров обуви</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Привет</td>
        <td>07.10.2016</td>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            Объединение столбцов
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>qwerty</td>
                    <td>12345</td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>asdf</td>
                    <td>789</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you please include the HTML code?

Comment: Sure! Hope it will usefully.